# Transform: translateX not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, shopify, css-transforms

so I'm having a problem that may have many different outcomes as a result. So basically I made a navbar for my mobile that goes from outside the screen (left side) to the right side so that it completely fills up the screen. I did this by using transform. translateX from -100% to 0%, and it works on basically every single device I tried besides my iPhone.

I tried it on another phone, tried it by making my google screen the smallest width it goes and I tried using inspect. And on all of those it works fine but my phone. I also tried deleting history and data from my safari browser, and tried using google on my phone, which also didn't work.

Here is the code I used:

```css
.nav-list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: darkmagenta;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

And then I used JavaScript to activate it, here is the code for that

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-list");
  //Toggle Nav
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
  });
};

navSlide();
```

My website is kuduzovic.myshopify.com and the password is soltew if anyone else wants to check it out and see if maybe this is just my phone not working properly. I also posted some images below so you can see what's not working properly.

Before I press the burger icon:
[image: before I press the burger icon]

After I press the burger icon:
[image: after I press the burger icon]

Google resized to the smallest width:
[image: google resized to the smallest width]

Google inspect:
[image: google inspect]

Comment: What is the computed left position of the nav-list? It looks as though that may be the problem rather than the translates not working properly.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I figured it out. Basically I wanted to move something a bit more to the left and since padding didn't work I used margin, but I wanted it only on desktop and didn't even think how it's going to affect mobile as well. But I fixed it now, thanks a lot.